# Create if not exists else update tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

I want to create table  if not exists,else update it.

this code is for create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book 
ID     INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Name   VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE,
TypeID INT(10),
Level  INT(10),
Seen   INT(10)
```

how can I change it to support update too?

**//EDIT**

I mean if I add a column,only add a column...not remove last data

If I remove a columns (for example remove TypeID INT(10) from the command) just that columns be remove...not all data

Comment: By "update," do you mean alter the table to add a column, or what? In SQL the word `update` means change the content of one or more rows. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Look up `alter table add column`.

Comment: You have this tagged as php, suggesting that you are looking to create or alter tables on the fly using web pages.  That seems like a very bad idea.  Maybe you should take a look at what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) to check the existence of tables

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT table_name 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
           WHERE table_schema = 'Databasename'
             AND table_name = 'tablename')

THEN
   ....
   ALTER TABLE Tablename...
   ....
ELSE  
   ....
   CREATE TABLE tablename...
   ....
END IF;
```